# SQL - Cast (String to NVARCHAR)

Tags: casting

Row 4 - I'm trying to make the 'on' syntax, to the right of the = sign, dynamic. This is based on a two digit year value from any particular date (e.g., 2021-08-31'). Row 5, commented-out, displays the original logic. Row 4, to the right of the = sign, contains my attempt at dynamic logic.

Note, the actual date will eventually be supplied by a Date/Time parameter in MS Visual Studio (BIDS/SSRS).

```
Column Types: In row 5, a.cui = PK, varchar(8), not null. b.cy21_cui = nvarchar(30), null

SELECT 'b.cy'+substring('2021-08-31',3,2)+'_cui' = b.cy21_cui. This looks correct but the type is not... it is not the correct type and will not join to a.cui.
```

My question is, how do I CAST `'b.cy'+substring('2021-08-31',3,2)+'_cui'` to a type that will join to `a.cui`? I've read all of the suggested threads here, based on the title of my question, and I cannot figure it out. I've testing a thousand CAST variations too.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
1 select distinct bn
2 from fc_2021 a
3 join M..rx_crsw b
----------------------------------------------------------------------
4 on a.cui='b.cy'+substring('2021-08-31',3,2)+'_cui'
5 --on a.cui=b.cy21_cui
----------------------------------------------------------------------
6 join nf_bsc..cvrg c
7 on b.abc=c.abc
8 where a.Eff_Date<='2021-08-31' and a.term_date>='2021-08-31' and PA_Type<>0
```

Comment: You cannot construct SQL identifiers like that. Search for "dynamic SQL".

Comment: Thank you mustaccio, do you know why that is?

Comment: Because the query parser doesn't know what the result of `substring('2021-08-31',3,2)` is and because `b.cy21_cui` and `'b.cy21_cui'` are very different things.

Comment: Ahh, got it. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Putting my code into a continuous string solved all of my problems... this allows for the parsing that I was looking to do. Please see my other post titled "MS Visual Studio (Reporting Services)". Note, I'm still searching for a legit answer to that question.